# Hide unwanted questions (Greasemonkey Script)

Tags: script, javascript, greasemonkey

### About

This Greasemonkey script enables you to hide questions you don't want to see. At the moment Stack Overflow gives you the option to "dim" or hide questions with [ignored-tags](/questions/tagged/ignored-tags) but doesn't allow you to tag individual questions in your lists. This plugin does just that.

### Download

[userscript-mirror.org](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/171393) - screenshots also available from this link.

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[Full code, screenshots, usage and description available here](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/171393)

```
try {
  if(!(hiddenQuestions=JSON.parse(GM_getValue('so-hidden-questions','[]'))))
    throw 'Invalid store questions: '+hiddenQuestions;
  console.log(hiddenQuestions);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
  GM_setValue('so-hidden-questions',JSON.stringify([]));
}

if( $('#question').length ) {

  $('#hmenus .mainnavs ul').append('<li><a href="#" id="nav-hidden-hide">Hide</a></li>');
  $('#nav-hidden-hide').click(function(){
    hiddenQuestions.push($('#question').attr('data-questionid'));
    setTimeout(function(){GM_setValue('so-hidden-questions',JSON.stringify(hiddenQuestions))},0);
    window.location = document.referrer;
    return false;
  });
  //...
}
```

#### License

Distributed under the BSD License

#### Platform

Tested on Windows 7, Firefox 21.0, Greasemonkey 1.9

#### Contact

Created & maintained by Precastic. Contact me through [my Stack Overflow profile](https://stackapps.com/users/21249/precastic).

#### Code

Written in javascript, using jQuery, running in Greasemonkey.
All contributions are welcome. Please contact me for more info.

This is my first Greasemonkey script and I struggled a bit with the limitations of the standbox, so have probably used questionable code in some places like `unsafeWindow.jQuery`. This will be updated as needed in the coming versions.

#### Future Enhancements

- I would like to implement an "ignored-on" timestamp so that old questions can be flushed without clearing all hidden questions when the user clears their hidden questions. This will help with performance without needing the user to start he/her list over.
- I would like to align this better with the look & feel of SO's ignore tags functionality, giving it a more Stack Overflow-like feel.

Comment: Actually, if you go to [your preferences page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/799588) (which only you can see), and check the ***hide ignored tags*** box, it will hide those unwanted questions, not just dim them. ... See, also, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/ignored-tags/info .

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks Brock. Nice to know the help is so well dispersed, I wish there was 1 help page that had an index to all the help instead of having to search for it ;)

Comment: They're [working on it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/182812/148310).  If you notice something wrong or missing (like this option) you can bring it up on meta.